# Help for writing a click event for a custom map

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, maps, photoshop

I have an image of the political map of the USA. I want to write separate click events for each of the 50 states in Visual Studio. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a static HTML map is what you want, then use an [ImageMap](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3528986/Image-Maps-in-ASPNET-20.htm) control

In winforms that may be a little more work than you want to do.

There are no 'shape' controls so you would have to define a virtual map and just monitor click events.

Your best bet is to use WPF or **Silverlight**. That would be a piece of cake. polys in WPF are first class citizens and have events. It will look real purty too.

And I am **sure** there are already defined maps xaml on the google. ([map](http://blogs.msdn.com/sskier/attachment/2227165.ashx), [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/sskier/archive/2007/04/22/united-states-map-in-xaml.aspx))

Comment: What I need is something like this :-(

http://www.americaslibrary.gov/es/index.php

Comment: Edited question. should cover all your options.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you get your hands on something like Macromedia Fireworks which allow you to create image maps.

This article explains how to do it using photoshop.

http://www.createblog.com/photoshop-tutorials/736-photoshop-image-maps/

Or even online web site

http://www.image-maps.com

Or even this

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:USA_imagemap_with_state_names

Comment: I am looking in my Visual Studio and I see no 'Macromedia Fireworks'. ;p

Comment: What I need is something like this :-(

http://www.americaslibrary.gov/es/index.php

Comment: sorry.. forgot my </sarcasm> tag